# Command line parameters to open Skype for Business chat room

Tags: skype-for-business

We use a persistent Skype for Business chat room and use it to broadcast daily the work done on particular projects. I'd like to launch Skype for Business each weekday morning and have it opened to this chat room. I thought to use Windows Task Scheduler and Skype for Business's command-line options to do this. The command for a specific contact is clear, e.g.:

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\lync.exe" sip:jsmith

...but how is this done for a chat room instead of a contact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably won't like the answer but you can't do that simply via Lync's command line.

What you are looking for is called *Persistent Chat Room*.  For that you need to use the [Persistent Chat SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/persistent-chat-sdk/lync-server-2013-persistent-chat-sdk-documentation).

What you could do is use a C# program e..g [How to: Send a message to a chat room](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/desktop/how-to-send-a-message-to-a-chat-room) to send messages to the persistent room.

You could have a [silverlight plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/desktop/create-an-add-in-for-the-persistent-chat-window) for the persistent room.

Comment: I do like your answer as it's definitive. What I asked can't be done. I really had hoped for a command-line solution so since launching a Skype chat room programmatically can't be done that simply I'll put this aside for now. It was a nice-to-have, not critical.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Microsoft Docs, you could try something like:

`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\lync.exe" im:<sip:user1@host><sip:user2@host>`

Source: [Starting Lync from another application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lyncserver/lync-server-2013-starting-lync-from-another-application)

Comment: This suggestion is similar to what I had tried as described in my question. It launches Skype with a chat initialized for an **individual**. i would like to launch Skype with a chat initialized for a **chat room** that's already been setup.

Answer (score 1):

conf:sip:https://meet.contoso.com/kazuto/7322994

Opens a Conversation window and displays meeting audio join options.